# How to convert number to bool in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to convert number to boolean,
but my if condition always run the else block statements.

```js
if ( !($(document).find($('.formSectionWrapper').length)) ) {
   console.log('IF')
} else {
   console.log('ElSE')
}
```

when length is 0 it runs else and when it is greater than 0 it run else block again!
What is my mistake?

Comment: `Description: ` Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.  so just declare a variable like this `var formSection = $(document).find('.formSectionWrapper') ; ` then `if(!formSection.length))`

Comment: Why not use logical operations? `$(document).find($('.formSectionWrapper').length>0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change

```js
if(!($(document).find($('.formSectionWrapper').length)))
```

to

```js
if(!($(document).find($('.formSectionWrapper')).length))
```

Note the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript 0 is falsy and positive numbers are truithy

so you can just check on the number.

[image: falsy and truthy examples in Js]

To answer your question:

Your logic looks wrong because of your `!` you are inverting the logic which is likely confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery Doc find](https://api.jquery.com/find/), you find an element not the `length`.

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of
> matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Then you apply the [if...else statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) on the `length`.

So here is how your code shall look like

```
const formSectionWrapper = $('.formSectionWrapper');
//const formSectionWrapper = $(document).find('.formSectionWrapper');
if ( !formSectionWrapper.length ) {
   console.log('IF')
} else {
   console.log('ElSE')
}
```